# Checking checkbox with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to set the checked property of checkboxes with jQuery, the jQuery code is working fine, but I got the problem in codebehind:

```
particular.click(function () {
    company.removeAttr('checked');
    particular.attr('checked', 'true');
});
```

Company and particular are the names of checkboxes, the jQuery code is working fine, my problem is in codebehind (.cs file)

```
if (particular.Checked)
{
    company_name_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
    cif_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
}
```

This is not working because Checked property is set on false when actually I'm setting it on true as you can see in the jQuery code, so where is the mistake?? For more explanation, I'm trying to disable some RequiredFieldValidators depending on which checkbox is checked, but as I told, Checked property is always set on false unless I set it on true by default in the element Checked=true, or particular.Checked=true in codebehind file, but that is not what I want to. I want to set on true the Checked property when I click the checkbox that's why I used jQuery.

**UPDATE**

My code

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{ 
   if (particular.Checked) 
   { 
      company_name_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
      cif_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
      contact_name_blank.EnableClientScript = false;  
      contact_cognames_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add a little bit more code that stands around the code you've pasted? Can you also show your page_load function please?

Comment: protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
           
            if (particular.Checked)
            {
                company_name_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
                cif_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
                contact_name_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
                contact_cognames_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
            }

           
        }

Comment: If particular is checkbox, use change event instead of click event

Comment: Have you tried using .prop() instead of .attr() ?

Comment: How do you get to your code behind? Do you have a button to submit your form?

Comment: is `particular` a dom reference or a jQuery wrapper? Try `particular.is(':checked')`

Comment: I tried using .prop() instead of .attr() and still not working. I changed the click event for change event, and still not working. Yes I have a button to submit my form. In addition at the begining of my jQuery code I have this: $(window).load(function () {
    companyName.hide();
    cif.hide();
    contactName.hide();
    contactCogname.hide();
    $("#part").css("background-color", "rgb(159,209,207)");
    particular.prop('checked',true);
}) When I debug with firebug, the checked property is set on true, but in codebehind is still on false, I don't know why...

Comment: If you have a button, then you should place your code that is in Page_Load in your function that handles your Button Click event in code behind

Comment: I think it won't slove my problem because I need to disable some RequiredFieldValidator depending on which checkbox is selected because I have some of them hidden so for example when I click particular checkbox I show some textboxes, if I click company checkbox I'll show other textboxes. So my problem is that I have all the RequiredFieldValidators in the same page so when I try to submit the form I need to disable(or force to validate them) the RequiredFieldValidators which are managing the hidden textboxes. Do you understand what I'm trying to??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your website you will have a button like this:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="btnClick" OnClick="btnClick_Click" Text="Click here" />
```

In your code behind you should have something like this:

```
protected void btnClick_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (particular.Checked) 
    { 
      company_name_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
      cif_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
      contact_name_blank.EnableClientScript = false;  
      contact_cognames_blank.EnableClientScript = false;
    }
}
```

You can remove the code in Page_Load and move it to the button click function

**UPDATE - Correct solution for question**

The correct solution is using the ValidationEnable Javascript function to disable/enable RequiredFieldValidators.

Code for this solution:

```
var emailEmpty = $("#registerContent").find('[id$=email_blank]'); //This is a jQuery object
ValidationEnable(emailEmpty[0], false); //This will disable the validator.
```

The reason we use "[0]" is because we need the DOM Element that is inside the jQuery object (see: http://api.jquery.com/get/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DCore%2Fget%26redirect%3Dno)

Comment: think it won't slove my problem because I need to disable some RequiredFieldValidator depending on which checkbox is selected because I have some of them hidden so for example when I click particular checkbox I show some textboxes, if I click company checkbox I'll show other textboxes. So my problem is that I have all the RequiredFieldValidators in the same page so when I try to submit the form I need to disable(or force to validate them) the RequiredFieldValidators which are managing the hidden textboxes. Do you understand what I'm trying to??

Comment: Okey, got it :) You need to disable your validators via Javascript. You can use the function ValidatorEnable that is provided in Javascript when you have validators present. An example: http://geekswithblogs.net/jonasb/archive/2006/08/11/87708.aspx Hope that is what you are looking for!

Comment: Ty, that's exactly what I'm looking for, I've just tried this: company.change(function () {
    $("#part").css("background-color", "");
    $("#comp").css("background-color", "rgb(159,209,207)");
    particular.removeAttr('checked');
    company.attr('checked', 'checked');
    userName.hide();
    cogname.hide();
    companyName.show();
    cif.show();
    contactName.show();
    contactCogname.show();
    ValidatorEnable(emailEmpty, false);
});  But the ErrorMessage is still fire, so it means that the Validator is still able, what am I doing bad??? Ty again ^^

Comment: How did you define emailEmpty ?

Comment: var emailEmpty = $("#registerContent").find('[id$=email_blank]'); I made sure it works fine because I tried with emailEmpty.hide() and it disappeared, so I think the problem is in ValidatorEnable(emailEmpty, false) why?? I don't know, hope you can help me to fix that.

Comment: you are using a jQuery object. That is not working for ValidationEnable. the jQuery object encapsulates the DOM element. Use ValidationEnable(emailEmpty[0], false) (reference: http://api.jquery.com/get/?rdfrom=http%3A%2F%2Fdocs.jquery.com%2Fmw%2Findex.php%3Ftitle%3DCore%2Fget%26redirect%3Dno)

Answer (score 1):

Try to use :checked filter

```
particular.is(':checked')
```