# Why isn't my checkbox checking with jquery?

Tags: html, jquery, magento

I'm using kojs in my project (Magento 2), and I'm calling a method that shows and hides an input box. The function is working (the box is showing/hiding based on the click), but the checkbox ins't getting its checkmark.

Any idea what's causing this?

Thanks

```
 <input class="sf-other-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="other" value="Other" data-bind="click: sfOther">
        <label style="margin-bottom: 0.5rem;" for="other">Other</label>
```

```
     sfOther: function () {
            $(this.sfOtherInput).toggle(this.sfOtherCheckbox.checked);
        }
```

Comment: Could Magento be disabling the default action when you bind an action?

Comment: can you add some more code so we can replicate the issue

Comment: @barmer I don't know. before I added the data-bind it was working, so possibly, but I don't know if it's the jquery that's doing it, or the kojs

Comment: @asmoun there isn't any more relevant code here

Comment: @webmaster https://jsfiddle.net/ahzuogmr/ here is how it looks like, the checkbox doesn't hide and show as you described, and you can check and uncheck it normally, what I'm missing?

Comment: Looks like this is a ko-js issue, not a jquery issue. I need to add another data-bind to "checked" in addition to the "click"

Comment: This is similar to what you are looking for. [Checkbox with Jquery ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17877866/checking-checkbox-with-jquery)

Answer (score 0):

Turned out to be a ko binding issue with Magento 2.

I had to use this syntax on my div

```
 <input class="sf-other-checkbox" type="checkbox" id="other-category" ko-checked="showSfOther" />
```

This toggles a variable that I have initialized in my js.
Then on the div that I want to show/hide, I added this

```
<div class="field sf-other-input required" if="showSfOther">
```

it's all toggling nicely